# Add Custom Field to Core Field Group

Tags: custom-fields

I'd like to add a custom field to the "core" demographics fieldgroup: the place of birth. I created a custom field, but I can't figure out, how to put it into demographics fieldgroup. Is it possible to do somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use JS to move custom field from custom group accordian to demographics accordian.

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/standards/javascript/

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot, and I'm now able to move fields. It lokks good, but if I edit on the Contacts Summary Page, of course, the fields are in their 'original place'. It's absolutely OK, I wrote this just to remember :)

Comment: Wow .. congrats for getting it work.

Answer (score 5):

You may find this new feature could deliver what you need - the MIH is still open and nearly fully funded iirc

https://civicrm.org/blog/colemanw/want-to-customize-the-contact-summary-screen

Comment: Pradeep's answer is most correct if you want to do it today - but if you can wait a week or two, this answer will dramatically simplify things.